# how i can add new tag in xml file by use linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

how i can add new tag in xml file by use linq to xml and i want the new tag the first tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings>
<Device>
  <username>fooo</username>
  <AgentName>fooo</AgentName>
  <password>fooo</password>
</Device>
<Device>
  <username>fooo1</username>
  <AgentName>fooo1</AgentName>
  <password>fooo1</password>
</Device>
</settings>
```

now i want to add a new tag to make file like that

```
<settings>
<IncommingConfig>
    <ip>10.100.101.18</ip>
    <port>5060</port>
</IncommingConfig>
<Device>
  <username>fooo</username>
  <AgentName>fooo</AgentName>
  <password>fooo</password>
</Device>
<Device>
  <username>fooo1</username>
  <AgentName>fooo1</AgentName>
  <password>fooo1</password>
</Device>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy using [`XContainer.AddFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344365.aspx), which adds the given value as the *first* child:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
doc.Root.AddFirst(new XElement("IncomingConfig", // Fixed typo in name
                     new XElement("ip", ipAddress),
                     new XElement("port", port)));
doc.Save("output.xml");
```

Comment: thanks Jon You are my idol :) but why you write doc.Save("output.xml");

Comment: @tito11: You said you wanted to "make file like that" which suggests you wanted to save the file after adding the new element. This is just an example of how to save the file. Obviously you can do it after adding more elements or whatever.

Comment: Jon i'am sorry i updated your answer , i think that my answer, i'am sorry another time, i can rollback

Comment: thanks again i asked because you write "data.xml" then you save  "output.xml" not `doc.Save("data.xml");`

Comment: @tito11: Well you didn't say you wanted to *overwrite* the original file. But examples like this are never meant to be taken *exactly* literally. Obviously I've no idea what filenames you really want.

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("...."));
XElement parentXElement = xmldoc.XPathSelectElement("settings");
XElement newXElement = new XElement("IncommingConfig");
.. 

parentXElement.AddFirst(newXElement);
```

Comment: Why bother using XPathSelectElement? It's the root element, which is *really* easily found...

Comment: Don't forget to explain your answer/code and link to references as well.

Comment: You are right Jon, i added this XPathSelectElement in order to find easily, but first element is simple